# How to apply index calculus methods to Silver-Pohlig-Hellman algorithm (discrete log for composite order)

Tags: finite-fields, discrete-logarithms

I've been reading up on index calculus methods, and I think I finally understand, it's an approach for writing relations like $x^k = f_1(x)^{j_1} f_2(x)^{j_2} ...$ for irreducible $f_i(x)$ of small degree, and finding a bunch of these relations so you can first solve for $f_i(x) = x^{k_i}$, then write the relations in log form to solve $k = k_1j_1 + k_2j_2 + ... $

But my question is how to combine with Silver-Pohlig-Hellman to get discrete log for a composite order system. For example suppose you have a degree-32 primitive polynomial, which has order $M=2^{32} - 1 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537$; you solve $(x^k)^{(M/m)}$ for each of the factors m then combine with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

How could I take an unknown $f(x) = x^k$, compute $g(x) = (f(x))^{65535}$, and use index calculus methods to calculate $g(x) = x^{k_g}$ in a group of order 65537 rather than in the full multiplicative group of order $2^{32} - 1$? SPH's strength is that it reduces the discrete log problem to one of its subgroups of smaller order, but I can't see how index calculus methods can take advantage of that... am I missing something?

(In this example for $2^{32}-1$ do you use polynomials that are smooth in powers of $x'=x^{65535}$ rather than in powers of $x$ itself?)

Comment: I'm not sure if index calculus works on a subgroup like the cyclic group of order 65537 here. Instead, I would combine using the Chinese Remainder Theorem with something like Baby Step - Giant Step on the big subgroups. I'm not an expert, so I'm prepared to be wrong.

Comment: it should... $g(x)=f(x)^{65535}$ is a generator with order 65537 as long as $g(x) \not\equiv 1$. The idea of "smooth" might be messed up though if I raise everything to the 65535th power.

Comment: Hmm. It might work. A problem might be that not all polynomials of $x'$ are in that subgroup. That might, indeed, mess up the expectations of being able to find enough smooth powers of $x'$. I wonder if there is a substitute for the case of the factor $2^n+1\mid 2^{2n}-1$ such as here?

Comment: ? really? I thought the idea of SPH was that you isolate on each of the groups of order $m$ by raising everything to the $M/m$ power, then that captures the "$m$-ness" of it (finding the logarithm modulo $m$), then you combine with Chinese Remainder Theorem at the end to get the discrete log in the overall group. Since $(x')^{65537} = 1$ then $((x')^k)^{65537} = 1$ for any integer $k$ and therefore $(f(x'))^{65537} = 1$ for any polynomial $f(x)$. All the finite field operations in this statement are in the original finite field, you just use $x'$ as a generator instead of $x$ to reduce order.

Comment: So for index calculus if you are looking for a factor base, you can't necessarily use $x+1$ as a member of the factor base since it may not be expressible as $(x')^k$. But I could use $(x+1)^{65535}$... it's just that this may not be an irreducible polynomial of $x'$ and it is probably not particularly smooth in terms of powers of $x$ from a computational standpoint.

Comment: May be I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to do index calculus using low degree polynomials $f_j(x')$ as a base, and look for exponents $k$ such that $x'^k$ factors into a product of those polynomials.

Comment: Not sure. The calculation base is still in the original finite field, I'm not sure where "smoothness" is determined, in terms of a polynomial in $x$ or a polynomial in $x'$.

Comment: But if $(x+1)^{65535}$ is a high degree polynomial in $x'$ is it ever gonna show up as a factor? High degree polynomials have only a few multiples that have degree less than that of the minimal polynomial of $x'$?

Comment: yeah that's what I meant by "is probably not particularly smooth in terms of powers of $x$ from a computational standpoint"